# unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main_getcmdline

Tags: c++, sdl-2

This is probably me being stupid but what am I doing wrong here? I'm not sure if I need the code but I'm doing this in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376811/linker-error-sdl-main-unresolved-in-main-getcmdline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376811/linker-error-sdl-main-unresolved-in-main-getcmdline)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly/64396980#64396980). That answer is for MinGW (not Visual Studio), but the same general principles apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you specified both assembly versions correctly in the linker? This means both for release and for debug.

Considering that you are using VisualStudio2019, I strongly advise you to use vcpkg - this is a package management made by Microsoft that simplifies the installation of libraries and other features in 1 line =)

Using it, you do not even need to enter the linker, and the official vcpkg website will help you configure it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that your project is linked with SDL2.lib and SDL2main.lib?

Comment: I did, inside link and input you mean?

Comment: Yep! Also provide the path for the lib's directory (link -> general -> Additional Library Directories)

Comment: I also did that, and it's still not working :(

Comment: This kind of error are mostly caused by incorrect linking, can you post your code and a screenshot of your configurations? a link to imgur or hastebin will do.

Comment: Could be the wrong signature used for the `int main()` function.